# Indentation and lacking space when using gb4e with minipages

Tags: spacing, indentation, minipage, gb4e

The normal behavior of a [`gb4e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) example environment is seen in (1) in the MWE below. But when I want two examples side by side, using `minipage`, the example is indented, and there is no space before or after the example environment.

How can I properly combine `gb4e` and `minipage` so that I get two examples side by side, but otherwise no differences from how it would look with a single example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, gb4e}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the spacing introduced by `gb4e` above and below, put `minipage` inside `gb4e`, not the other way around:

```
\lipsum[4]
\begin{exe}
  \item[]\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
     \ex Left example
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
     \ex Right example  \label{rightex}
  \end{minipage}
\end{exe}

The right-column example is numbered (\ref{rightex}).

\lipsum[4]
```

The `\ex` command works correctly despite the intervening `minipage` environment. Note the empty `\item`, and the comment character between the `minipage` environments to avoid a stray space.

With this method, the vertical spacing is exactly that introduced by `gb4e`; and the left example is indented the same as ordinary (one-column) examples.

Comment: Your and David's examples work equally well, and it's not clear to me what's better between embedding `exe` within `minipage` and use `flushleft` (@DavidCarlisle) and embedding `minipage` within `exe` and use `\item[]`.

Comment: Well, it would be hubris to claim that I have a better solution than David Carlisle, but if I'm not mistaken, his will give you the vertical spacing provided by the `center` environment. It may *look* like what `gb4e` inserts, but it strikes me as the wrong approach-- the results will diverge if you customize the behavior of `gb4e`.

Answer (score 2):

The line with the minipages is over-full because of a paragraph indent before the first minipage, and a word space between them.

You could use `\noindent\begin{minipage}` but here I use `center` which also sets `\parindent` to zero and re-adds suitable vertical spacing. I used `%` to remove the word space between the boxes. (It might be better to have a space between them, in which case they need to be less than `.5\linewidth`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, gb4e}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\end{minipage}%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exe}
\ex An exe environment
\end{exe}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I also just noticed is that when I added a label after the `\ex` command, the normal vertical space appeared above the example. Why would that happen?

Comment: @Sverre minipage tries to act like a real page and discards space at the top, but a `\label` would prevent that space being discarded if it ends up being placed as the first node in the vertical list

Comment: The problem with `center`, though, is that it precisely centers the examples. That might be appropriate for some cases, but for my current case, I'd like it to be left aligned, with the same indentation as a normal example has. Is there an easy way to achieve that? Other than inserting spaces like `\medskip`?

Comment: @Sverre since you have two boxes with a total width of `\linewidth` `center` `flushright` or `flushleft` are all the same thing, none of them produce any horizontal movement.

Comment: In this case, that's true, but in my real scenario, I'm using `{0.3\linewidth}`. So I tried `flushleft` now, but the vertical space above the minipages is much larger than the one above an `exe` environment that's not in a minipage. I think this is due to the combined effect of having both `flushleft` and a `\label` after the `\ex`.

Comment: @Sverre you could use \mbox{}\label{..} or just put the label after some of the text so it is in the first line,not above it

Answer (score 0):

Adjustable-width minipages, using expl3.

[image: adjustable mpp]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse} % now part of the kernel


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \gltwoex } { O{0.45} O{0.45} +m +m } { 
    % 1==width % ex1
    % 2==width % ex2
    % 3==ex1
    % 4==ex2
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 } % 1st example
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #4 } % 2nd example
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { #1\linewidth }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { #2\linewidth }
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim}
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
\end{minipage}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{exe}
\gltwoex[0.35][0.60]{
\ex
\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\
}
{
\ex
    \gll Das  ist einer dieser   sehr langen Sätze,    die  es in der a b deutschen Sprache gibt.\\
         this is  one   of.these very long   sentences that it in the a b German    language gives\\
}
\end{exe}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{exe}
\gltwoex{
\ex
\gll The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\\ 
       DA ADJ1 ADJ2 N V PREP DA ADJ1 N\\
}
{
\ex
    \gll The cat sat on the mat.\\ 
          DA N V PREP DA N\\
}
\end{exe}




\end{document}
```